# Qt Qml best way to pass model through loader

Tags: qt, qml

what is the best way to pass any model (for example a ListModel in main.qml) through loader into an other .qml file?

Answer (score 4):

If the model only needs to be set once, then you can simply do that in the onLoaded signal handler

```
Loader {
    id: loader

    source: "myelement.qml"

    onLoaded: item.modelProperty = yourModelId;
}
```

If it needs to be a binding, e.g. if the model is stored in a property which will change during runtime to a different model instance, then a Binding element should work

```
Binding {
    target: loader.item
    property: "modelProperty"
    value: theModelStoreProperty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is really only one way to use a loader. Pass the url of the qml file to the source property.

From http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html#details

```
Loader {
       id: myLoader
       source: "MyItem.qml"
    }
```

It sounds like this is not quite what you are asking though. If you can provide more details on what you are doing we may be able to provide more help.

Comment: thank you deadron, but i want to pass a model trough loader like a var using bindings Binding{id:someID; target:Loader.item; property: "someModel"; value: modelName} any idea?

Comment: sorry there is smth wrong in the binding of my last comment: property:"modelName"; value: someModel

Comment: I still have no idea what you are attempting to do that is not handled by the standard behavior of a loader.  You are free to assign a property binding to the source property on the loader.